# Grails - remove from join table and delete the hasMany objects

Tags: grails, grails-orm, has-many

I have the following domain classes:

```
class Shift {
    //etc
}
```

and

```
class Schedule{
    //etc
    static hasMany = [shifts:Shift]
    //etc
}
```

Currently In a delete controller action I do a schedule.shifts.clear() and then a schedule.delete(). This deletes the schedule record itself and the associations in th ejoin table, but the shift objects are still in existence. How do I delete these also at the same time?

Answer (score 0):

Solved doing this:

```
def shifts = schedules.shifts
shifts*.delete()
```

Answer (score 0):

You must provide the `back-ref` to enable the cascading delete:

```
class Shift {
  static belongsTo = [ schedule:Schedule ]
}
```

then you should be able to do `schedule.delete()` to remove also the shift-instances